# json_encode not returning value on production server

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am wondering if someone can help me.  I am using a simple ajax script and i have a json_encode returning success or error.  On wamp server/localhost everything works as it should, however on the production server it does not seem to be returning the value.  I cannot figure out why it would have a problem

AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-extra").bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    var parent2 = $(this).closest('td');
    var string = 'id='+ parent.attr('id').replace('record-','') ;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_add_keyword.php',
        data: string,
        beforeSend: function() {
            parent2.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },

        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'success'){
                        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                            parent.remove();
                        });
            }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                parent2.animate({'backgroundColor':'#eeeeee'},300);
            } else {
                parent2.animate({'backgroundColor':'#000000'},300);
            }
        },          

    });
});
```

});

The ajax_add_keyword.php simply updates a table and returns;

```
    if($affected_rows == 1){
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';  

}else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';  
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

I have set an extra else in the AJAX to turn the background black and this is what is happening (after the table has been updated so i know that it is only the return where there is a problem).  As I say it was all fine on the localhost and I cannot find what has changed.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try adding `dataType : 'json'` to your ajax function options

Comment: And that's what I was missing (always the simple things)!  Perfect, working now, thank you

Comment: what do uou have in you browser console?

Comment: You're welcome !